# Finding the font in a css file with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to string some regex together to find all the fonts used in a css file. So far I have as follows.

```
var regExp = /font-family:(\w+);/;
var matches = regExp.exec("font-family:arial; font-family:berch;");

//matches[1] contains the value between the parentheses
console.log(matches);
```

This matches only 'arial'. How can I make it carry on searching to find also 'berch'?

Comment: You might want to consider with css this format is also common ... `font-family:"Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `g` modifier to your regex.

```
var regExp = /font-family:(\w+);/g;
```

`g` (global) modifier says not to stop after the first match and match the pattern as much it  can.

Also don't use `exec`. use `string.match`.

```
"font-family:arial; font-family:berch;".match(/font-family:(\w+);/g);
```

Comment: I assumed this, but still only 'arial' is matching

Comment: You might want to explain `"Also don't use exec. use string.match"`

Answer (score 1):

It may just be a case of including the global flag:

`/font-family:(\w+);/g`

Answer (score 0):

By default, a regex will return only the first match. If you want to make it return all matches, you need to add the global `g` flag:

```
/font-family:(\w+);/g
```